# How to use typeof in Object.prototype

Tags: node.js

I've created an object prototype, and am trying to check the 'typeof' 'this', but it always returns 'object'.

```
Object.prototype.testme = function() { return typeof this }
```

And then

```
'test'.testme(); // returns 'object' instead of 'string'
```

So in the prototype, if I add

```
console.log(this)
```

I get:

```
[String: 'test']
```

How do I just test the *value* with typeof in a prototype? I know I can define prototypes based on the type, but I need a catchall as there will be null values etc...?

Comment: `typeof this` will always be an object

Comment: Also, you shouldn't be extending native types, it's bad practice

Comment: Yet the object itself knows what type of object it is, so there must be a way of querying the property? The reason I'm extending the native object, is that otherwise if .test() gets called on the wrong object type, it will cause an error. That's why I want to call my prototype, and then decide what to do with it based on what type it is! Seems perfectly logical to me?